# regarding adding image import

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i do this in didselectmethod of uitableview

1- `[tableView reloadData];`
2- `cell.cell_ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayMainMenuOnImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

after this 2 line it gives exc bad access please help me why this happen

Comment: show your code and error log !

Comment: arrayMainMenuOnImages are not in bundle then provide current image refrence to cell's imageview.

Comment: @Maulik yes this is custom cell

Comment: What is your requirement?After user selects any row it should display image?Then why are you reloading tableview?

Comment: @NuzhatZari if user select a row then it show the images from arrayMainMenuImages.  but if he already selected some row and after that he is trying to select another row then previous selected row image change by some another arry and currently selected row image change by  arrayMainMenuImages     sorry i m not making it clear  please help..

Comment: Shows image for selected row only right?

Comment: If you have to change only selected row image than no need to reload tableview, remove [tableView reloadData];.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//  put your code in this way  in didSelect: method

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *imgName = [arrayMainMenuOnImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *img ;
if(imgName)
  img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
else 
  img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage.png"];
[cell.cell_ImageVIew setImage:img ];
[tableView reloadData];
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . You need to add image to your cell_imageview and then do [tableview reloaddata]

```
cell.cell_ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayMainMenuOnImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[tableView reloadData];
```